# add auth validation in Django

Tags: django, authentication

I have a django application and I want to add my own auth validation and check if the user is expired (check the expiration date from some of my models). I want to raise a ValidationError in the login page with appropriate message if user is expired. What's the best way to do that?

Thanks, Alex

Comment: Where does django.contrib.auth fall short of what you need?

Comment: I need to check the expiration date in one of my models and give appropriate error if the user is expired while he tries to log in.

Comment: Alright, normally it's done in the view of the application using the auth module. Another approach would be to create a manager that you can override objects.get() and do the checking. The only major benefit to extending the auth module is that you already have a tested and working implementation of cookie validation that already supports what you need. Take a look here for some additional reading: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-in-views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you REALLY want to do your own custom authentication, you should read [custom backends](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#handling-authorization-in-custom-backends) in the Django Documentation.

You probably don't want to do your own though. It sucks. Really. Unless there is a really really good reason, you should avoid your own authentication. The main reason being, that many django apps stop working if you don't use the built in User model. If you need to authenticate against an existing source, that's a valid reason for creating your own backend. But there are pitfalls, and you still probably want to use the built in User model for your custom backend.

You should tell us why you want to do your own custom authentication, and perhaps we can help you achieve your requirement, without writing a custom backend.

**Edit**

Ok, I think I understand what you mean now. What (I think) you want, is a custom authentication form. We currently use custom form (though we have a different unavoidable backend), so you should be able to use the following quite easily.

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django import forms
from myproject.myapp.models import MyClass

class CustomAuthForm(AuthenticationForm):

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(CustomAuthForm, self).clean()
        user = self.user_cache # set by super class
        if user.my_class.expired:
            raise forms.ValidationError('This User has Expired!')
        return cleaned_data
```

Then, to use this custom authentication form, you need a URL in your `urls.py`:

```
from myproject.myapp.forms import CustomAuthForm

url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', name='login', 
    kwargs={'template_name':'youproject/login.html', 'authentication_form':CustomAuthForm}),
```

I see now that your question originally stated you wanted custom validation, not authentication. My apology for not reading your question correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast reply. I want to disable access for the expired users. There is an admin user that sets user's expiration date and if the user is expired I want to show him appropriate message while he tries to log in.

Comment: @alex, so are you using a custom User model to do this?

Comment: No, I use django's User model